# (A-Frame) local gltf wont load; Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe, gltf

I took the code from the [A-Frame School](https://aframe.io/aframe-school/#/11) in which a gltf model is loaded. Then I loaded the Sample Models from Khronos, [this box](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/tree/master/2.0/Box) and tried to load it, but I get this error (several times)

```
GLTFLoader.js:979 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined
at GLTFLoader.js:979
at i (GLTFLoader.js:570)
at GLTFLoader.js:975
at <anonymous>
```

I can load .obj models and tried the several versions of the model, but get always the error.
The sample code does work locally, meaning it loads the model correctly, getting it from the aframe cdn.

Heres the code for completion

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>glTF Model</title>
    <meta name="description" content="glTF Model">
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/aframevr/aframe/b395ea0/dist/aframe-master.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>
      <a-assets>
        <a-asset-item id="boxModel" src="Box.gltf"></a-asset-item>
      </a-assets>          
      <a-gltf-model src="#boxModel"></a-gltf-model>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those models are in the 2.0 folder which means you need glTF v2.0 loader. A-Frame 0.5.0/0.6.0 supports glTF v1. But glTF v2 will be supported in A-Frame 0.7.0, but you can use `gltf-model-next` from Don McCurdy:

https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/blob/master/src/loaders/gltf-model-next.js

Or you can grab different models instead from the 1.0 folder: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/tree/master/1.0

Answer (score 2):

Replace Aframe version to this:

`<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.7.1/aframe.min.js"></script>`